# Search then copy and to location - rename if exit

Tags: search, batch-file, copy, dos, rename

Ok I need a batch file that does the following and for the life of me I cannot seem to get it to work.

1. Searches the entire `C:\` drive for all *`*.PST`* files
2. Copies these files to a network drive location (*`j:\@PCBackup\PST`*)
3. If more than one file exists with the same name, rename instead of overwrite

So if the following exists:

```
c:\archive.pst
c:\user\archive.pst
```

the output would be something like:

```
:\@PCBackup\PST\archive1.pst
:\@PCBackup\PST\archive2.pst
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done as follows:

```
@echo off

FOR /F "usebackq delims=;" %%I IN (`dir C:\*.pst /s /b`) DO (
    IF NOT EXIST "j:\@PCBackup\PST\%%~nxI" (
        CALL :COPYFILE "%%I"
    ) ELSE (
        CALL :RENAME "%%I"
    )
)

GOTO :EOF

:COPYFILE
COPY "%1" "j:\@PCBackup\PST"
GOTO :EOF

:RENAME
FOR /L %%N IN (1, 1, 1000) DO (
    IF NOT EXIST "j:\@PCBackup\PST\%~n1%%N%~x1" (
        COPY "%1" "j:\@PCBackup\PST\%~n1%%N%~x1"
        GOTO :EOF
    )
)
```

Note that in the last `FOR` loop, I'm trying to find the next file name to use whenever a file name conflict occurs. I've set the maximum counter value to 1000, which should be more than enough to prevent all similar file name problems.